# How to search data of last 30 days with elasticsearch alias

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I am using elastic search as a events data storage. I have created an alias with rotation of 30 days, total retention period of event will be 2 year, so I will have total Index 24.

I want to limit the scope of data according to query time period, like if I have to search data for last 30 days then It should max 2 Index for search rather than all 24 Index

Answer (score 1):

[Filtered alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/aliases.html#filter-alias) to the rescue!! You can define an alias over all indices with a filter to only query the last 30 days, like this:

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "my-index-*",
        "alias": "my-alias",
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "@timestamp": {
                    "gte": "now-30d/d"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, when searching over `my-alias` you only query the last 30 days of data, whatever the number of indices that the alias spans.

Comment: this will restrict entire alias to return only last 30 days data and it will not support query time filter which he asked in question.

Comment: I must have misunderstood (monday mornings), sorry about that. I'm leaving the answer as it might help other use cases.

Comment: no worries. you are helpful to everyone from long time and i always admire you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bool query with must and filter clause. This will query only last 30 days data from your alias or index.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-30d/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not have default timestamp field, I  do have custom field for event time, will it work like timestamp?

Comment: what is data type of custom field which store event time ?

Comment: {"type" : "date", "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}

Comment: yes it should work. insted of `timestamp` just give your event time field name and check.

Comment: I added `"profile":true` to analyze the search query, but i think it is searching in all index.
and is there any difference in query performance between `"gte": "2022-02-18 22:41:10"` and `"gte": "now-30d/d"`?

Comment: see it will search in all index and then apply filter to send only result of last 30 days. as i know there is no diffrence in query performance as `now-30d/d` will be convert to relative date only while query. If you want to search only 2 index then please check answer given by @val but in that you need to update filter in alias if you want to increase or decrease number of days.